# XML value (to NSString)  to float

Tags: iphone, xml, nsstring, floating-point

I'm parsing an xml file using TBXML.
One of the value is a latitude coordinate (e.g. 45.503508).
I need to read that and converting into a float variable.

I'm doing this

```
TBXMLElement *loc_latitudine = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"latitude" parentElement:loc_location]; //read the xml attribute
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [TBXML textForElement:loc_latitudine]];
float myfloat = [string floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", myfloat);
```

what's the problem? 
If my xml value is 45.503508, the value of "myfloat" is 45.000000!
Every time!

What is wrong?

Comment: NSLog(@"string: %@", string); is "45,503508".

Comment: Does using `[string doubleValue]` (as opposed to floatValue) make *any* difference?

Comment: no one :( i've tried to replace "," with "." in the string but nothing!

Comment: Ah - didn't notice the comma. How are you trying to replace it? (Presumably the NSString `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method?)

Comment: yes yes, i've tried... but nothing changed!!

Comment: YESS! sorry! i replaced the "," with "." only with float value. not with double!!! Now it works! thank you :))

Comment: Cool. I'll add an answer for prosperity - feel free to accept it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that there's a comma (instead of a period) in the string returned from the XML element.

As such, you should be able to swap this out with a period using the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method and then use the NSString `doubleValue` method to extract the figure you require.